# Feedback vertex set and disjoint cycles (directed graphs)

Tags: graphs

I've looked at the feedback vertex set and thought about connecting the problem to finding vertex disjoint cycles.

My first thought was that if there are at most k vertex disjoint cycles in a graph, then k is a bound for the feedback vertex set problem and there is a subset of k vertices satisfying the requirement (i.e. there exists a subset of size k s.t. the graph without the subset is cycle-free)

However, I easily found this example that refutes it:
[image: graph example]

Here there is only 1 disjoint cycle, but we have to remove 2 vertices from the graph to obtain a cycle free graph.

My question is, can we find a bound for the feedback vertex set problem by looking at disjoint cycles? (for example, for graphs with at most k disjoint cycles the feedback vertex set is bounded by 2k, or maybe even by k+1 as I've shown here)

P.S. I'm asking specifically about digraphs.

Comment: It's a pretty good *lower* bound -- you must select at least one vertex from each disjoint cycle.  Getting an upper bound seems harder.